# SQL How to do a conditional sum by distinct id?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, aggregate-functions

Suppose you have result set such as:

```
DATE          ID    cost    
---------------------------------------
 01/01/2011    1     10      
 01/01/2011    1     10      
 01/01/2011    2     10      
 01/01/2011    2     10
```

I want a way to sum the values on cost but only once for every distinct ID so that when i group by date I get a result such as

```
DATE            cost
```

---

```
01/01/2011         20
```

I first tried something like

```
    sum(distinct cost)
```

but that of curse only returns 10
I also tried:

```
sum(case when distinct id then cost else 0 end)
```

but that is not a functional query.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: Are the cost values always the same for a given ID?

Comment: This is oracle, I cannot group by date and Id, as I need 1 row per date.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I will assume that the same ID will always have the same cost in the same day. I will also assume your RDBMS supports derived tables. In that case, this is what you want:

```
select date, sum(cost)
from 
  (select distinct date, id, cost from YourTable)
group by date
```

**Updated**

Oracle derived tables do not require alias.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you want to do here is group by both date and id, as MPelletier wrote.

FWIW - you can do a distinct inside an aggregate in some dbs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

And even better, use group by with rollup to get totals along with the grouping:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
SELECT DATE, ID, SUM(cost)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATE, ID WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some flaw with the logic of the posted question.

Suppose you have this result set:

```
DATE          ID    cost    
---------------------------------------
 01/01/2011    1     10      
 01/01/2011    1     15     
 01/01/2011    2     10      
 01/01/2011    2     10
```

What should the query return?

```
DATE          cost    
---------------------------------------
 01/01/2011    20
```

or

```
DATE          cost    
---------------------------------------
 01/01/2011    25
```

The accepted answer will return `35`.

Or is such a set impossible to have?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the database/SQL engine:

<strike>SELECT Date, Sum(Cost)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Date, ID;</strike>

```
SELECT Date, First(TCost)
FROM
(SELECT Date, Sum(Cost) as TCost FROM YourTable GROUP BY Date, ID)
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Unless of course there's something I'm not understanding right from the question.

Comment: with this approach you'd have two records for each date.

Comment: @WillA I'm having trouble with the wording of the question, it seems. Anyways, I think @Adrian's got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
 SELECT dates, Sum(cost) as TCost FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY  ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this hack.

Concatenate the value you want to sum - `cost` - with the `id` field and insert a letter - for example an 'a' between them. You can use `DISTINCT` to these concatenated fields to use them only once in the aggregate function.

When you use `SUM`, these string fields automatically casted as integer, MySQL will cut it at the first letter.

> The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may
> convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(cost),
    SUM(DISTINCT cost),
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cost, 'a', id)),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cost, 'a', id)),
    SUM(DISTINCT CONCAT(cost, 'a', id)) expectedSum
FROM (
    SELECT '2011-01-01' AS date, 1 AS id, 10 AS cost
    UNION ALL SELECT '2011-01-01', 1, 10
    UNION ALL SELECT '2011-01-01', 2, 10
    UNION ALL SELECT '2011-01-01', 2, 10
) __tmp
GROUP BY
    id
```

Be careful! This is **not** a nice generic SQL solution, this is a trick. I am not sure it will work on every special case.

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT SUM(cost) AS Expr1
     , ID
     , date
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date
            , ID
            , cost
         FROM table_name AS table_name_1
        GROUP BY date, ID, cost) AS derivedtbl_1
 GROUP BY ID, date
```

or THIS

```
SELECT     SUM(cost) AS Expr1,  date
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT date, ID, cost
           FROM table_name AS table_name_1
           GROUP BY date, ID, cost) AS derivedtbl_1
 GROUP BY date
```

Comment: I wish people comment what's wrong when they downvote.

Answer (score -2):

**Try This**
I am using Mysql for this.
DEMO TABLE(Table name is 'tablename'. id and cost is type of 'int' )

```
id | cost  
 1 | 15  
 1 | 25  
 1 | 10  
 2 | 25  
 2 | 5  
 2 | 10  
 3 | 20    
 3 | 15    
 3 | 10    
 4 | 20    
 4 | 20
```

Query use

```
select id
     , SUM(cost) as 'Total Cost' 
  from sumchk 
 group by id
```

**OR (use below one)**

```
select id, sum(cost) as 'Total Cost'  
  from (select * 
          from tablename
  ) a  
group by id;
```

**Result :**

```
  id  |  Total Cost  
   1  |    50  
   2  |    40  
   3  |    45  
   4  |    40
```

Comment: It would be thankful if you tell me the scenario in which case..this solution is not working..